# how can i work with compass value from onsenserchanged.because it is changing continuously

Tags: android, math, augmented-reality

I am working with sensor. i want to calculate compass value and work with that value,i want to compare with my calculate angle value.but the problem is it changing continuously and i am unable to calculate things.

Comment: Answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877155/how-to-make-an-accurate-compass-on-android) question is helpful I think.
And also these two : [android compass seems unreliable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256256/android-compass-seems-unreliable) and [Compass give me crazy data, is calibration needed or it's the sensor broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462346/compass-give-me-crazy-data-is-calibration-needed-or-its-the-sensor-broken)

Comment: Thanks i will try with these links.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lowpass filter for seneor values, and it worked for me.

[Smoothing Sensor Data with a Low-Pass Filter](http://blog.thomnichols.org/2011/08/smoothing-sensor-data-with-a-low-pass-filter)